# struct.pack(!i, 10) result is "00 00 00 0d 0a" on Windows

Tags: python, struct, pack

I found an odd problem with Python's `struct.pack("!i", 10)` on a Windows system. I get the buffer and save it in to a file, but the result is

```
 00 00 00 0d 0a
```

where on Mac OSX, the result is

```
00 00 00 0a
```

What does the `0d` mean?

When I pass `11` instead of `10`, the result is `00 00 00 0b`. So I think when I pass `10`, the result should be `00 00 00 0a`.

If I want to get `00 00 00 0a` when I pass `10`, what should I do instead?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with struct packing, as you could have found out yourself.

Answer (score 7):

> What does the `0d` mean?

It means `'\r'`

> If I want to get `00 00 00 0a` when I pass `10`, what should I do instead?

Try to open file in binary mode:

```
with open('file', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(struct.pack("!i", 10))
```

When you try write `'\n'` (`0a`) to a file on Windows and the file is opened in text mode, Python adds `'\r'` before `'\n'`.

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> In text mode, the default is to convert platform-specific line endings (`\n` on Unix, `\r\n` on Windows) to just `\n` on reading and `\n` back to platform-specific line endings on writing. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data is fine for text files, but will corrupt binary data like that in `JPEG` or `EXE` files. Be very careful to use binary mode when reading and writing such files.